# Does Apache Camel support redelivery when using JPA and transactions with Spring Boot?

Tags: hibernate, transactions, apache-camel, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Hibernate JPA and a transacted Camel route. The processor uses JPA to find an existing row and if it can't find one then creates the row. When running in parallel a race condition exists and a route will occasionally throw a `MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException`. A simple redelivery of the route should fix things.

When the exception is thrown the transaction is marked as rollback however Camel does not start a new transaction but tries doing the redelivery using the old transaction.

This causes Hibernate JPA exceptions on the redelivery such as (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

How can I get Camel to end the current transaction before doing the redelivery?

```
@Component
public class MyEventRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    MyEventProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        SpringTransactionPolicy requiresNew = new SpringTransactionPolicy(transactionManager);
        requiresNew.setPropagationBehaviorName("PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW");
        errorHandler(transactionErrorHandler(requiresNew).maximumRedeliveries(2));

        from("direct:myRoute")
        .transacted()
        .process(processor)
        ;

    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I came up with the following as a workaround but there must be a more elegant solution:

```
@Component
public class MyEventRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    @Autowired
    MyEventProcessor processor;

    @Autowired
    PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:myRoute")
        .onException(MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class)
            .maximumRedeliveries(0)
            .useOriginalMessage()
            .handled(true)
            .to("seda:deadletter")
            .markRollbackOnly()
        .end()
        .transacted()
        .process(processor);

        from("seda:deadletter")
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${body} == null"))
                .stop()                     
        .end()
        .choice()
            .when(simple("${exchangeProperty.redilveryAttemptCount} == null"))
                .setProperty("redilveryAttemptCount", constant(1))
            .when(simple("${exchangeProperty.redilveryAttemptCount} < 3"))
                .setProperty("redilveryAttemptCount", simple("${exchangeProperty.redilveryAttemptCount}++"))
            .otherwise()
                .stop()
        .end()
        .to("direct:myRoute");
    }
}
```